# Can one use Window.Onscroll method to include detection of scroll direction?

Tags: javascript

Can one use Window.Onscroll method to include detection of scroll direction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you record the scrollX and scrollY on page load and each time a scroll event occurs, then you can compare the previous values with the new values to know which direction you scrolled.  Here's a proof of concept:

```
function scrollFunc(e) {
    if ( typeof scrollFunc.x == 'undefined' ) {
        scrollFunc.x=window.pageXOffset;
        scrollFunc.y=window.pageYOffset;
    }
    var diffX=scrollFunc.x-window.pageXOffset;
    var diffY=scrollFunc.y-window.pageYOffset;

    if( diffX<0 ) {
        // Scroll right
    } else if( diffX>0 ) {
        // Scroll left
    } else if( diffY<0 ) {
        // Scroll down
    } else if( diffY>0 ) {
        // Scroll up
    } else {
        // First scroll event
    }
    scrollFunc.x=window.pageXOffset;
    scrollFunc.y=window.pageYOffset;
}
window.onscroll=scrollFunc
```

Comment: +1: that's what I was going to say too. The only things I have to add is that there might be some sort of input device that lets you scroll freely (not constrained to just X or Y), so I'd break the one big IF into two. If it's the first scroll, you could also assume that it's going down or right. Also, you might need to check what happens with intrapage links (eg: href="#top").

Comment: Works really well! Wonder how I might be able to calculate velocity of scroll?

Comment: I think you can get the timestamp of the events.  Find the difference between two consecutive events and divide the diffs calculated above by the timestamp difference.

Answer (score 2):

With jquery, you can also register a custom scroll event which supplies the scroll change as an argument to the event handler:

```
var previous_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
        scroll_change = scroll - previous_scroll;
    previous_scroll = scroll;
    $(window).trigger('custom_scroll', [scroll_change]);
});
```

Then instead of `scroll`, bind to `custom_scroll`:

```
$(window).on('custom_scroll', function pos(e, scroll_change) {
    console.log(scroll_change);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble making this work in ie8 (although it is compliant for ie9, FF and Chrome) - all scrolls seem to be detected as horizontal.

Here is a modified script [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deborah/2d7Ct/) that also works in ie8 and may cover a few more browsers.

```
function scrollFunc(e) {

   function getMethod() {
        var x = 0, y = 0;
        if ( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
          x = window.pageXOffset;
          y = window.pageYOffset;
        } 

        else if( document.body && (document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop ) ) {
          x = document.body.scrollLeft;
          y = document.body.scrollTop;
        } 

        else if( document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ||     document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {
          x = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
          y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }

         return [x, y];
    }

    var xy = getMethod();            
    var xMethod = xy[0];           
    var yMethod = xy[1];

    if ( typeof scrollFunc.x == 'undefined' ) {
       scrollFunc.x = xMethod;
       scrollFunc.y = yMethod;
    }

    var diffX = scrollFunc.x - xMethod;
    var diffY = scrollFunc.y - yMethod;


    if( diffX<0 ) {
       // Scroll right
    } else if( diffX>0 ) {
       // Scroll left
    } else if( diffY<0 ) {
       // Scroll down
    } else if( diffY>0 ) {
       // Scroll up
    } else {
       // First scroll event
    }
    scrollFunc.x = xMethod;
    scrollFunc.y = yMethod;
}

window.onscroll=scrollFunc​
```