# Jquery Tools Scrollable left or right?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools, scrollable

How I can detect in which directions I scroll or type with my keyboard. Like how I detect if it left or right.

Comment: Hiya, There is a good proof of concept residing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222915/can-one-use-window-onscroll-method-to-include-detection-of-scroll-direction ;(Capturing X and Y axis movement) hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the event object to get which event was triggerd MouseWheel or Keyboard

```
api.onBeforeSeek( function () { console.log(event);})
```

But I don't more using Jquery Tolls Scrollable because I was not best for my application.

I'm using now http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/ this much more powerful and flexible to use.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a handler that detects a keydown event and then checks to see which key was pressed. Each keyboard key has an identifying number, which you can check and then handle appropriately. If it was the left arrow do one thing, if it's the right arrow, do another.

This question has been answered elsewhere on stackoverflow:

[Binding arrow keys in JS/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery)

You can read more about .keydown() at the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) site.

Comment: Has the scrollwheel from the mouse a detection too? Because on my scollable I can scroll horizontally.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that part of your question. I don't have any experience with it directly, but it's possible that http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ might have what you're looking for. It seems you can attach that event handler to the window object in addition to individual elements. It might catch all the different inputs that result in a scroll?