# javascript (but not jQuery please) fixed position on x-axis but not y?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I've looked everywhere and so far have not found a non-jQuery js to handle this. I would like to avoid using a library for just this one simple task.

I would like to fix three navigation divs ("#header", "#tabs" and "#footer") to viewport left (or alternatively, to the x position of a div "#helper" with "position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;") -- but not fix y. They can not be vertically fixed.

I've created a working js that forces the divs to reposition based on scrolling, but it's not smooth in the real page (too many dynamic and graphic elements) - I'd like it to either animate smoothly, or mimic fixed-left and not appear to reposition at all.

Anyone who can give pointers or a quick script, or review and modify the script I have made? I've noticed people tend to ask why an obvious solution is not used instead of answering the question... I will be glad to answer, but would prefer help with the actual problem.

Here is a jsFiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BMZvt/6/

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for people who view this post - I wound up going with the solution I initially put together in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMZvt/6/) that used a simple javascript to mimic fixed x.

The javascript in the first answer was hefty and wound up buggy, and the second answer sounded good but did not work in practice. So, I'm recommending the javascript from the jsFiddle (below) as the best answer to fixed x and fluid y without a javascript library. It's not perfect and has a minimal delay but is the best answer I've found.

```
function fixLeft() {

            function getScrollX() {
                var x = 0, y = 0;
                if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
                    x = window.pageXOffset;
                } else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollLeft) ) {
                    x = document.body.scrollLeft;
                } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollLeft) ) {
                    x = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                }
                return [x];
            }

            var x = getScrollX();
            var x = x[0];

        // have to get and add horizontal scroll position px
        document.getElementById('header').style.left = x + "px";
        document.getElementById('tabs').style.left = x + "px";
        document.getElementById('footer').style.left = x + "px";
    }

    window.onscroll = fixLeft;
```

Answer (score 3):

Smooth animation example:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');

var moveTo = function(obj, target) {
    // start position
    // you should obtain it from obj.style
    var cpos = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }        
    var iv = setInterval(function(){
        cpos.x += (target.x - cpos.x) * 0.3; // 0.3 is speed
        cpos.y += (target.y - cpos.y) * 0.3; // 0.3 is speed
        obj.style.left = Math.floor(cpos.x) + 'px';
        obj.style.top = Math.floor(cpos.y) + 'px';
        var dist = Math.abs(cpos.y - target.y); // distance (x+y) from destination
        dist += Math.abs(cpos.x - target.x); // < 1 = object reached the destination

        if(dist < 1) { // here we are checking is box get to the destination 
           clearInterval(iv);
        }
    }, 30); // this is also the speed
}

box.onclick = function(){
    moveTo(box, {x: 90, y: 75}); // fire this function to move box to specified point
}
```

- **Demonstration**: http://jsfiddle.net/Qwqf6/5/

Your script is your job, but this is a quick start how to solve animation problem

You can also do some fancy stuff with speed for example use `sin(x)` to set the speed

- **Demonstration #2** http://jsfiddle.net/Qwqf6/6/ (very smooth)

---

- **Full script here** https://gist.github.com/3419179

Comment: I'm having trouble making this work for my use case. For scrolling, it has to measure the start and end position based on start scroll and end scroll and then do the smooth repositioning, for each interval, right? What's the best way to replace the strict value of "90" for x in your script with something that can handle the scrolling?

Comment: Make `cpos` global variable and just set starting position. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Qwqf6/8/. `target.x` will be your `getScrollX()` result i think.

Comment: @DeborahSpeece i made this script for you https://gist.github.com/3419179 enjoy :) i changed `position:fixed`, made `iv` global, and i added `clearinterval`

Comment: that is so charming! :) I used your script in a jsFiddle jsfiddle.net/wvfX9/43 but it is not repositioning - did I do something wrong?

Comment: @DeborahSpeece I had to change my script a lot. Here you go: https://gist.github.com/3419901 - the most important thing is my script now can handle many divs.

Comment: @DeborahSpeece one more thing - change `this.iv[obj] = false;`,`clearInterval(this.iv[obj]);` to `MoveEffect.iv[obj] = false;`,`clearInterval(MoveEffect.iv[obj]);`  cause script is producing tons of errors

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straight way to do this...

But here's a way.

First, You need to be able to detect the direction of the scrolling when window.onscroll event happens. You would do this by comparing the current page offsets with the newly acquired page offsets whenever the scroll event happens. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222915/can-one-use-window-onscroll-method-to-include-detection-of-scroll-direction)

Now suppose you know the direction of the scroll, you want to change the styling for the divs depending on the direction of the scroll.

Let **FixAtX** be the value of the x coordinate that you want to fix your divs at.
Let **OriginalY** be the y coordinate of the divs.
Also whenever scrolling happens, despite of the direction, you want to remember the pageoffset X and Y. Let's call them **OldX** and **OldY**

If scrolling vertically:

- Set position value for divs' style to be absolute.
- Set top value for divs' style to be **OriginalY**
- Set left value for divs' style to be **OldX + FixAtX**

If scrolling horizontally:

- Set position value for divs' style to be fixed.
- set top value for divs' style to be **OriginalY - OldY**  (<- this may be different depending on how the browser computes pageOffset value,)
- Set Left value for divs' style to be **FixAtX**

I think this should work...
Since you are just using browser's rendering for positioning, it should be very smooth!

hope I understood the question correctly.

Comment: I think this is what the script I'm using is basically already doing - it's repositioning the div with a style="left: (scroll value);". But it looks jerky in the real page and needs smoothing, or for repositioning not to happen - for the desired divs to just stay left to the viewport (but not be fixed vertically), and not move or appear to reposition on scroll event at all.  Here's a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/BMZvt/6/

Comment: Well, I guess I wasn't clear enough. My code does NOT 'update' any values. It uses the 'position:fixed' styling to make the browser re-position the divs. you make the position fixed if you are scrolling horizontally and absolute if you are scrolling vertically.

So you would only need to change the style value for position once, when you figure out the direction of the scrolling. you are not constantly 'updating' the position.

Comment: Oh. Yes, it took a bit to really understand this (not a js pro). This actually seems to be a superior method, but I'm having trouble translating it into code. 

I was able to make the scroll direction listener work (and posted an improvement that works in ie8 on the link), but for multiple divs at different y positions in the window, it's getting complex to track the "old y" for each one. I'll post the solution when it's working.

Comment: Hi Euimin - this solution does not work. Once the style is set to "fixed" for any element, other elements must also be set to "fixed" to keep their position. So, once the header and tabs are set, content and any other top-level containers must also be set to fixed and have their Y values calculated (not scalable as content changes). Also, the elements jump noticeably when they change from fixed to absolute. Thank you for the answer, though.